# RecyclerView Items seems to be float

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView`. Some items are in the download state, and are updating constantly with the growth of downloaded bytes. As it is shown in the following image,  when I scroll, items are not fixed in their position; as the downloads finish, the problem goes away! Any Idea to solve this problem?

> Please note that changing images after finishing each download is not my problem. The major problem is floating behavior of Items in the RecyclerView.

[image]